# Can not convert from inherited class "No suitable constructor exists to convert from "QStandardItem *" to "FolderItem""

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, inheritance, types

Hi I am in the process of trying to impliment subclass of the qt library supplied QStandardItemModel and QStandardItem to display items in a Qtreeview.  Everything seems to work fine except for when I try to retrieve the selected object from the tree view and use it as a parent object to add children too.
The issue is that the selected object retrieves as the inherited type "QStandardItem" and not my subtype "FolderItem":

```
FolderItem KSLgui::GetSelectedFolder()
{
    QItemSelectionModel * model = ui.folderView->selectionModel();
    QModelIndexList indexes = model->selectedIndexes();
    return (FolderItem)folderModel.itemFromIndex(indexes.first());
}
```

I get an error telling me that no sutible constructor exists to convert from the two types.  I have overloaded all the constructors for both types when making my subtypes and tried to make a new constructor that excepts QStandardItem as a parameter which appears to fix the error but doesn't function properly as it only returns an empty object and not the selected object:

```
FolderItem::FolderItem()
    : QStandardItem()
{
}

FolderItem::FolderItem(const std::string & text)
    : QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(text))
{
}

FolderItem::FolderItem(const QIcon & icon, const QString & text)
    : QStandardItem(icon, text)
{
}

FolderItem::FolderItem( int rows, int columns)
    : QStandardItem(rows, columns)
{
}

/* returns empty
FolderItem::FolderItem(QStandardItem * stanitem)
{
} */

FolderItem::~FolderItem()
{
}

int FolderItem::type() const
{
    return 1001;
}

FolderStructureModel::FolderStructureModel(QObject *parent)
    : QStandardItemModel(parent)
{
}
```

I have included what I beleive to be the significant code.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have solved the issue myself.  I had to cast to the right type of point I believe.  I am not getting an access violation however...  but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Better don't use C-Style casts - they are unsafe. Better use static_cast. (FolderItem)...itemFromIndex(...) is wrong, as a QStandardItem* (pointer) is returned, but you return a FolderItem object. You should return a FolderItem* and use static_cast (if you're sure about the type).